# Getting Lighthouse CLI Error - Invalid URL when using batch file to request

Tags: javascript, batch-file, lighthouse

I've got a batch file which is:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\yarrytroshchey\Lighthouse\Demo\urls.txt) 
DO (
ECHO Line is: %%a
lighthouse -output html –quiet –chrome-flags="–headless" %%a
)
```

and a urls.txt file which is:

```
https://www.bbc.co.uk
https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport
https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/formula-1
```

I am trying to run a batch audit through Google Lighthouse on the URLs listed in the txt file and I encounter the error -

Runtime error encountered: lighthouse-core/lib/lh-error.js | urlInvalid # 0
LHError: INVALID_URL
    at lighthouse 
 (C:\Users\yarrytroshchey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\index.js:44:11)
    at chromeP.then._ (C:\Users\yarrytroshchey\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-cli\run.js:191:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

I've tried modifying the URLs but have not been successful.

It should simply run each URL through lighthouse and output a HTML report in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `--` instead of `–` or `-` and whilst you're at it, placing the options after the, *preferably doublequoted*, metavariable:

```
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("C:\Users\yarrytroshchey\Lighthouse\Demo\urls.txt"
) Do @LightHouse "%%A" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless"
```

I've missed off the `--output` option as it is unnecessary, *because `html` is the default*

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using a bash script as an entrypoint for Docker. I did solve this using environment variables on docker run and pointing it in the script, instead of a direct argument.

For example, the entry-point.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeo pipefail

lighthouse --no-enable-error-reporting --chrome-flags="--headless --disable-gpu" $URL --output json html
```

With that in place, you just need to feed the env variable URL with the "https://www....." in your next docker run.